# Amazon S3 redirects not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, hosting

I have a static site hosted on S3 and I'd like to set a 301 redirect from www.example.com/2000/200/2/ to www.example.com.

I tried creating a directory structure:

```
/2000/200/2/index.html
```

and using S3's console to set a redirect in the Metadata properties, but this didn't work.

Next I tried a bucket rule that looked like:

```
<RoutingRules><RoutingRule>
<Condition><KeyPrefixEquals>http://www.example.com/2000/200/2/</KeyPrefixEquals></Condition>
<Redirect>
<HostName>www.example.com</HostName>
<Protocol>http</Protocol>
<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
</Redirect>
</RoutingRule></RoutingRules>
```

But now when I go to the /2000/200/2/index.html I just see the page. So neither redirect worked! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things:

**First**, this is the rule I used.

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>xx/x/xxxx/xxxxxx</KeyPrefixEquals>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <HostName>www.example.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Slightly different than Amazon's sample formatting, but it works.

**Second** I noticed that Firefox was removing this segment of the XML: "" after I save the snippet. Moved over to Chrome and no issues.

**Lastly**, I had to connect the site to the S3 website endpoint instead of the API endpoint, including in CloudFront.

**Long story short**, the AWS Static Site Tool works well, but if you use it as a starting point and then the complexity of your requirements increase, it'll have made some incorrect choices for you!

Comment: Btw I worked through some of these issues in a blog post: http://cloudconfusing.com/2017/12/24/amazon-s3-website-vs-rest-api-endpoint/

Answer (score 1):

The [Configure a Bucket for Website Hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) shows redirect examples such as:

```
  <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>docs/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>documents/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>
```

and

```
  <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
       <KeyPrefixEquals>images/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>folderdeleted.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>
```

These have the `<KeyPrefixEquals>` equal to the path relative to the root, rather than including `http://www.example.com`. Try matching that format.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I keep getting:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>...

Comment: So if somebody accesses `www.example.com/2000/200/2/foo.html` they would be redirected to `www.example.com/foo.html`. That destination file would need to be accessible in terms of permissions. But it's hard to tell whether it's a permissions problem or a "file not found" problem.

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue, but what permissions would those be? Thanks!

Comment: You could start by creating a temporary Bucket Policy that [makes everything public](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). If it still gives an error, then the redirection isn't working.

Comment: current bucket policy is: 
`{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "AddPerm",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-website-SITE/*"
  }
 ]
}` 
so I think that's done? Not sure why the redirect policy and setting the error document to "index.html" are not being respected. Quite a puzzle!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein for me its redirecting but showing bucket name instead of domain name `[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "about/contact"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "contact"
        }
    }
]`